# LSTM concatenation training

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, rnn

I'm using a Lasagne network, but this is a pretty generalized question:

say I ingest N number of tweets using the same LSTM, grab the final output of each to make a NxOutputSize tensor (`Merged_output`) to be condensed into a small 10-vector output through a shallow neural net. What would be the best way to train this LSTM?

Thanks